# How to save values of multidimensional array to db in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multidimensional-array

I have a bit multidimensional array like this one:

```
[[2, 1], [751, 159], [793, 195], [978, 527], [938, 783], [977, 881], [713, 592, 101], [337, 248, 143], [444, 647, 196], [913, 763, 211], [752, 746, 225], [862, 878, 373], [876, 900, 597], [719, 904, 236, 11], [448, 836, 883, 59], [486, 723, 241, 150], [864, 611, 619, 167], [558, 796, 707, 353], [915, 683, 738, 534], [641, 777, 892, 107, 78], [264, 310, 161, 574, 114], [549, 849, 596, 181, 160], [633, 471, 497, 438, 262], [351, 485, 544, 772, 348], [890, 941, 572, 418, 374], [776, 972, 1001, 729, 379], [595, 898, 989, 771, 454], [84, 514, 914, 571, 442, 19], [335, 97, 689, 314, 879, 20], [869, 828, 802, 859, 553, 34], [298, 134, 564, 614, 411, 62], [175, 579, 490, 399, 479, 72], [382, 830, 215, 691, 624, 85], [922, 840, 657, 917, 436, 95]]
```

As you can see, each sub array has between 2 and 6 values.

I have a model called "Sub" with db columns "sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4", "sub5", "sub6".  (values for sub3-6 would be null if the sub array only had 2 values)

What is the proper way to save each sub array to a db row?

I have tried this:
    @m = [the big array I mentioned above]

```
      @m.each do |t|
        Pair.create(:sub1 => t[0], :sub2 => t[1], :sub3 => t[2], :sub4 => t[3], :sub5 => t[4], :sub6 => t[5])
      end
```

But for some reason that creates a table that does this: (sample of "sub1" column)

2
2
751
2
751
793
2
751
793
978
2
751
793
978
938

See what's happening there?  It repeats each but adds one more row each time.

Here's my model:

```
class Pair < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :sub1, :sub2, :sub3, :sub4, :sub5, :sub6
end
```

UPDATE: I figured out the issue...  I had the create method in the wrong part of a script and that was causing it to run several times in a row in a weird way.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: What database are you using? Postgres, at least, actually supports Array types (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/arrays.html). It should be fairly straightforward to create a column that stores one of those. Which would also let you access the values in the array in the database, which might be handy at some point.

Comment: I am using Postgres, so that's definitely good to know.  To clarify though, I'm looking to only save one value in each subarray to it's own column in the row.  For instance: if one subarray was [1, 2], I'd be looking for my row to have these values: :sub1 => 1, :sub2 => 2, :sub3 => null, :sub4 => null, :sub5 => null, :sum6 => nul

Comment: Huh. I don't actually see anything wrong with the code you provided - that's how I'd do what you describe, certainly. Perhaps you can gain some insight by watching the server log while it runs, maybe add some logging code during the loop's iterations?

Comment: I'm an idiot...  Found the issue and it was completely unrelated.  Thanks for the help anyway! :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to serialize the column. See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize at the **Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns** section.

Comment: I only need to save one value per column though.  Would serializing still help in that situation?  So for instance, if one subarray was [1, 2], I'd be looking for my row to have these values: :sub1 => 1, :sub2 => 2, :sub3 => null, :sub4 => null, :sub5 => null, :sum6 => null